# Jenkins pipeline not failing stage on batch failure

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a jenkins declarative pipeline if I add a step like this:

```
bat '''dir QWERTY'''
```

it will fail the stage as expected since there is no such directory.

However this is a bat script with many statements so I want to fail as soon as there is an error. I have been used to appending `|| exit /b` to handle that. But as part of jenkins pipelines this does not seem to work.

```
bat '''dir QWERTY || exit /b'''
bat '''dir QWERTY || exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%'''
```

None of the above fail the stage. Why?

A third option:

```
bat '''dir QWERTY
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
'''
```

seem to work though but that hurts the readability of the script.

Comment: Can you please try `bat '''dir QWERTY && echo success || echo Failed'''` and post which it printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out in a Jenkins pipeline I can't use `/b`. Thus:

```
bat '''dir QWERTY || exit'''
```

works.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be it. `exit /b 1` works for Jenkins everywhere except within an `if` in a batch file. It must be simply `exit 1`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not currently have Jenkins, so I cannot really test all the methods, but technically you can test if the chain works by:

```
bat '''dir QWERTY && echo success || echo Failed'''
```

This should print one of the 2 commands, if `failed` was the message, the process should work. You could then setup a more readable string:

```
bat '''dir QWERTY && echo. || exit /b'''
```

You could retain your `if %errorlevel%` method, by calling a label:

```
bat '''
:error
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b!

dir QWERTY & call :error
dir AZERTY & call :error
'''
```

Comment: The echo command indeed prints Failed, but replacing it with `exit /b` again did not fail the stage. In the end it turned out that if I drop the `/b` and just `exit` it works. This part confused me since in my old non-pipelined jenkins setup it worked with the `/b`.

Comment: That is strange. and if you `exit %errorlevel%` without the `/b`, it should also work?